# Build succeeds even though the editor shows errors and and installation of NuGet package fails

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017, I have a solution with the following projects:

```
My.Project
My.Project.Commons
Test.My.Project
Test.My.Project.Commons
```

In one of the test files from `Test.My.Project`, I have this statement:

```
using My.Project.Commons;
```

If I hover over it, it shows this error message:

> The type or namespace name 'Commons' does not exist in the namespace
>   'My.Project'(are you missing an assembly reference?)

However if I Clean and Build(or Clean and Rebuild) the solution, there are no errors.

When I try to install a NuGet package, I get the same error:

> The type or namespace name 'Commons' does not exist in the namespace
>   'My.Project'(are you missing an assembly reference?)

So why does my build succeed?

I believe that my `Test` projects are not built properly, because I can't run any tests.

On another solution however, I can run tests with no problem, so I doubt there is an issue with Visual Studio as a whole(just with my current project).

I tried:

1. Restarting Visual Studio.
2. Removing all projects from the solution and adding them back.

None of these things worked though.

Comment: Did you check the MSBuild log? Tried to build your solution with the MSBuid command line tool?

Comment: No, because from what I understand, in a managed code project, the MSBuild log is the same as the Output window from Visual Studio. And in the Output window of Visual Studio, there are no errors shown

Answer (score 1):

If you are using resharper, suspend and resume resharper and it will refresh the cache

If you go into VS options resharper you will find the  the options

Comment: I can't find ReSharper in `Tools->Options` or in `Help->Microsoft Visual Studio`. I did install it a couple of months ago.  I'm not sure what happened to it.

Comment: It was probably the free trial, so it's not active anymore. Anyway, another solutions builds find so I don't think ReSharper is causing this.